# HOW TO TRANSFER ERC1155 NFT TO ANOTHER WALLET

Tags: nft, erc-1155, wallet-transfer, sendtransaction, receive

I Have A Ethereum ERC 1155 NFT in my Trust W.  I want to send it to my MetaMask Wallet.  Do I send this NfT to my MetaMask the same way as if I was sending a regular NFT?. Like normally sending a BNB SmartChain ERC 721 I send it to my Recieveing SmartChain address.
So where this ERC 1155 is Ethereum you send it to your receiving address even if the NFT has a diffrent ERC #.
Obviously I should be able to answer this because I bought it but now that I think about it I think when I connect my wallet it did it automatically. So anyways. DO I SEND THIS Ethereum ERC 1155 NFT to my Recieving Ethereum Address?

Comment: For clarity.. I ment so where it is Ethereum based ERC 1155 I se d it to my Ethereum recieving adress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the NFT to the recepient address.